# Cannot edit imported data in Libreoffice Base

Tags: csv, libreoffice-calc, libreoffice-base

I am using Libreoffice Base for my International GCSE ICT exam. I am practicing with past papers, but I can't get it to work. The files provided come as separate csv files, which have to be imported.

I have tried the following:

- Importing the csv files directly from Base

  Importing the csv file to Calc, then import the file to Base

  Create a 2nd database, and copy the tables from the imported DB to the new file.

No matter what I try, I just can't seem to edit anything. All the editing options are greyed out (even things like cut, paste, etc...)

Can someone please help me?

**EDIT:** It has to work on linux, specifically Fedora 25.

Comment: Not sure I fully understand the question, but often I need to do a "save as" before being able to edit some fed - either because their initial location is read-only or I'm trying to use features not supported by the original type.

Comment: I've tried that, but it doesn't work. There seems to be issues with the primary key. I've seen some sites that say save it as a dBASE file, but I don't have that option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the comment [here](https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/93185/cannot-edit-imported-data-in-base), I should first create a database, make a table in design view, import the csv into Calc, copy it, then paste it into the table in Base, and choose "append data".